# Camera capture didn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I try to use camera in WP 8.1 universal app. But app crash.
I try di this:

```
private MediaCapture mediaCaptureMgr = null;
async void ShowPreview()
{
    if (mediaCaptureMgr == null)
    {
        mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
        await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();

        myCaptureElement.Source = mediaCaptureMgr;
        await mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
}
```

and I try this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868171.aspx
but both crash app when I initialize MediaCapture 
            await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
VS output windows show me message 
WinRT information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you declare the webcam capability?

Comment: Yes. I try code into emulator, and all work excellent. But in my Lumia 925 app crash when I call await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();

Comment: The problem may be when you hadn't stopped previous Previw. Can you check if you are able to start Camera for the very first time after restarting the Phone? I've written a [small post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/) about taking a photo - maybe it will help.